# Laravel - Using post method in controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm new to laravel and I'm still trying to learn.

This my code in my controller:

```
public function index(User $user){

    $posts = $user->posts()->with(['user', 'likes']);

    return view('users.posts.index', [
        'user' => $user,
        'posts' => $posts,
        ]);
    }
```

And this is the code on blade.php

```
{{$user->name}}
```

I've also tried checking if the code:

```
dd($posts = $user->posts()->with(['user', 'likes']));
```

and it seems fine since it's returning data from the database. With these codes it was supposed to show the User's Post on a different page when you click on the User's name. The problem is that it only shows the user's name but not the user's post. I'm only following a tutorial but the result was different with the tutorial and the one that I'm doing. Can someone please help?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Only `$posts = $user->posts` will return your desired results.

Comment: if you want to show user's post when you click on name, you should put that in  a tag ( <a> ) and write route for that and return user's post

Comment: Hello. I've already tried checking with this $posts = $user->posts but unfortunately it not the desired result. This code works though, anyway thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are trying to lazy eager load the `posts` relationship on this `$user` and load the `user` and `likes` relationship for those posts. You can try to use `load` to load these relationships on the Collection:

```
$posts = $user->posts->load('user', 'likes');
```

Or `load` on the User instance:

```
$user->load('posts.user', 'posts.likes');
$posts = $user->posts;
```

If you are not trying to have these relationships loaded on the `$user` but you just want the posts with their relationships you can eager load them off of the relationship itself:

```
$posts = $user->posts()->with('user', 'likes')->get();
```

Comment: Yes. This is what I'm trying to ask sir. Thanks. I did copied your answer and it still show a blank page but after putting it on DumpandDie the data were still there. It just doesn't show on the page. I don't know why this happens though. Thanks you again sir.